# Show that for each $s \in S$ there exists an integer $0 \leq k < n$ such that $s = e^{\frac{2i \pi k}{n}}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{C}^\times$ the multiplicative group of complex numbers different of zero. Let $S \subset  \mathbb{C}^\times$ a subset such that the subgroup generated by S has $n < \infty$ elements. Show that for each $s \in S$ there exists an integer $0 \leq k < n$ such that $s = e^{\frac{2i \pi k}{n}}$.

I already know that $s$ could be represented by the exponential function, but I don't know how to prove this. Is anyone can explain to me how to do it? (This is only a preparation exam)

Comment: I think something is wrong.  The numbers $e^{2\pi ik/5}$ are $5$th roots of unity.  There are other finite subgroups of $\mathbb C^\times$ other than the $5$th roots of unity.

Comment: I think that denominator should be $n$ and not $5$.  I see you fixed the title but not the body of the question.

Comment: Could we use Lagrande theorem to solve the problem here.

Comment: Yeah, first you show $s$ must be on the unit circle.  Then use the fact that $s^n=1$.  For what $e^z$ do you have $(e^z)^n=1$?  It means $nz$ must be a multiple of $2\pi i$.

Comment: But why should it be on the unit circle and which property garantee this?

Comment: Is it by definition that $s^n=1$?

Comment: The general complex number is of the form $s=re^{ix}$, where $r$ is the distance to the origin and $x$ is the angle with the real axis.   If you raise $s$ to a power $s^n$ then the distance of $s^n$ to the origin is $r^n$.  If $r^n=1$ for some $n$ then $r=\pm 1$.

Comment: My last question : Why $s^{O(<S>)} = s^n = 1 $ for all $s \in S$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$  be a finite multiplicative subgroup of $C\backslash \{0\}$ with $|G|=n$.Then $\forall g\in G (|g|=1).$ For if $g\in G\land |g|\ne 1 $ then $|g|^a\ne |g|^b\to g^a\ne g^b$ for distinct $a,b\in N$. So for any $g\in G$ we have $g=\exp (2 \pi i v(g))$ with $v(g)\in [0,1)$. We have $\exp (2\pi i n  v(g))=g^n=1 $ because $|G|=n.$ Therefore $n v(g)$ is a non-negative integer $k$. So $v(g)=k/n$. And $k<n$ because $v(g)<1$. Hence $G\subset H=\{exp (2\pi i k/n) :0\leq k<n\}.$ But $G=H$ because $|G|=|H|=n$.